# Beamer Overlays Greek - Subsection Number in Definition Changes

Tags: beamer, numbering, overlays

I am using Beamer in PDFLaTeX to prepare a presentation in Greek. I have defined a definition environment which uses subsection numbering. I have a definition that is two slides long. Therefore, I use overlays. However, the subsection counter in the definition is not "overlays aware" and increases from 1.2 in the first slide to 1.3 in the next one. I would like to keep it 1.2 in both slides.

I have used so far, without success,

```
\setcounter{section}{0}
\setcounter{subsection}{1}
```

as well as `\addtocounter{subsection}{-1}` and `\resetcountonoverlays{subsection}` at the overlayed frame of interest. None of these options worked in my case.

Here is a MWE (2-3 packages might not be needed in this particular example, sorry about that, I am relative new to this and wanted to ensure that the MWE will indeed run):

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169,notheorems]{beamer}

\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}

\mode<presentation> {
\usetheme{Rochester}
}

\usecolortheme{whale}

\usepackage[T1,LGR]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage{tempora,newtxmath}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsfonts, amsthm, amsmath, ragged2e}
\hypersetup{unicode}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{tikz, graphicx, graphics}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[justification=justified,width=\linewidth]{caption}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{bm}

\usepackage[skins,theorems,most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage[makeroom]{cancel}

\captionsetup{skip=0pt,belowskip=0pt}

\definecolor{MyRed}{RGB}{134, 8, 8}

\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]

\apptocmd{\frame}{}{\justifying}{}

\newtcbtheorem[number within=section,list inside=thm]{theorem}{Θεώρημα}%
{colback=green!5,colframe=green!35!black,colbacktitle=green!35!black,fonttitle=\bfseries,enhanced,attach boxed title to top left={yshift=-2mm,xshift=-7mm},width=.9\textwidth,arc=.7mm}{th}
\newtcbtheorem[number within=section,list inside=defn]{defn}{Ορισμός}%
{colback=blue!5,colframe=cyan!35!black,colbacktitle=blue!35!black,fonttitle=\bfseries,enhanced,attach boxed title to top left={yshift=-2mm,xshift=-2mm}}{def}

\makeatletter
\def\tcb@cnt@theoremautorefname{Θεώρημα}
\def\tcb@cnt@defnautorefname{Ορισμός}
\makeatother

\title[]{Σημειώσεις \\
Για Κάτι}
\author[]{Συγγραφέας Συγγραφίδης}
\institute[]{Το Ινστιτούτο}
\date{\vfill}

\setlength{\parskip}{.5em}


\AtBeginSection[]
{
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Περιεχόμενα}
  \tableofcontents[currentsection]
\end{frame}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[noframenumbering]
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Περιεχόμενα}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\addtocounter{framenumber}{-1}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{
  \scriptsize\insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber
}

\section{Εισαγωγή}

\begin{frame}{Εδώ ο Ορισμός}
\justifying
\only<1> {\begin{defn}{Ορισμός για Κάτι}{}
\begin{itemize}
\justifying
\item Μπλα Μπλα Μπλα $x(t)$.
\end{itemize}
\end{defn}}
\only<2> {\begin{defn}{Ορισμός για Κάτι (συνέχεια)}{}
\begin{itemize}
\justifying
\item Μπλα μπλα μπλα $\mathbf{x}(t)$.
\end{itemize}
\end{defn}}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169,notheorems]{beamer}

\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}

\mode<presentation> {
\usetheme{Rochester}
}

\usecolortheme{whale}

\usepackage[T1,LGR]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage{tempora,newtxmath}
\usepackage{amsthm, ragged2e}
\hypersetup{unicode}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[justification=justified,width=\linewidth]{caption}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{bm}

\usepackage[skins,theorems,most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage[makeroom]{cancel}

\captionsetup{skip=0pt,belowskip=0pt}

\definecolor{MyRed}{RGB}{134, 8, 8}

\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]

\apptocmd{\frame}{}{\justifying}{}

\newtcbtheorem[number within=section,list inside=thm]{theorem}{Θεώρημα}%
{colback=green!5,colframe=green!35!black,colbacktitle=green!35!black,fonttitle=\bfseries,enhanced,attach boxed title to top left={yshift=-2mm,xshift=-7mm},width=.9\textwidth,arc=.7mm}{th}
\newtcbtheorem[number within=section,list inside=defn]{defn}{Ορισμός}%
{colback=blue!5,colframe=cyan!35!black,colbacktitle=blue!35!black,fonttitle=\bfseries,enhanced,attach boxed title to top left={yshift=-2mm,xshift=-2mm}}{def}

\makeatletter
\def\tcb@cnt@theoremautorefname{Θεώρημα}
\def\tcb@cnt@defnautorefname{Ορισμός}
\makeatother

\title[]{Σημειώσεις \\
Για Κάτι}
\author[]{Συγγραφέας Συγγραφίδης}
\institute[]{Το Ινστιτούτο}
\date{\vfill}

\resetcounteronoverlays{tcb@cnt@defn}

\AtBeginSection[]
{
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Περιεχόμενα}
  \tableofcontents[currentsection]
\end{frame}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[noframenumbering]
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[noframenumbering]{Περιεχόμενα}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{
  \scriptsize\insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber
}

\section{Εισαγωγή}

\begin{frame}{Εδώ ο Ορισμός}
\justifying
\only<1> {\begin{defn}{Ορισμός για Κάτι}{}
\begin{itemize}
\justifying
\item Μπλα Μπλα Μπλα $x(t)$.
\end{itemize}
\end{defn}}
\only<2> {\begin{defn}{Ορισμός για Κάτι (συνέχεια)}{}
\begin{itemize}
\justifying
\item Μπλα μπλα μπλα $\mathbf{x}(t)$.
\end{itemize}
\end{defn}}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, `\resetcounteronoverlays{tcb@cnt@defn}` is exactly what I was looking for! (When you see the solution, the mechanism behind it makes perfect sense. I learned something new today!)

Comment: @Kotsos You're welcome!